# How to use rbt (for review-board) to aquire 'All Incoming Review Requests' from command line

Tags: command-line, review-board

My team uses review-board (https://www.reviewboard.org/)
I want to use it from the command line instead of the web to know what are my incoming requests.

To see all my outgoing review requests I am using:

```
rbt status
```

But I could not find a command that is giving all the incoming review requests.

Am I missing something?

Is there a tool that uses the API and does it?